# How to optimize finding all meeting conflicts below O(n^2)

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I'm writing a basic planner from scratch using Django, but in this case ignore the framework, and the language itself.

Problem:
Given n events, show **ALL** conflicts that an event has with other events. Assume that the events given are sorted by `start_time`.

Additional requirement:
If event A is in conflict with event B, the conflict must be shown twice - One time when mentioning all conflicts with event A, and another time when mentioning all conflicts with event B.

I have tried following some solutions for problems related to this, but the algorithms involved did not output all conflicts and did not meet the additional requirement.

So far this is what i have right now. Assume that `Event` is a combined data structure that contains fields `start_time` and `end_time`.

```py
def overlap(interval_1: Event, interval_2: Event):
    if interval_1.start_time < interval_2.end_time and interval_2.start_time < interval_1.end_time:
        return True
    return False


def list_conflicts(events: List[Event]):
    results = defaultdict(list)
    for i in range(len(events)):
        event_selected = events[i]
        for e in itertools.islice(events, i):
            if overlap(event_selected, e):
                results[e].append(event_selected)
                results[event_selected].append(e)
    return results
```

Comment: Put all event starts and ends into one list, then go through this list to detect overlaps, keeping track of currently active events as you go through the list.

Comment: @hyde It should work, given a stack-based tracking approach and proper time tokenization. Going to write something up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a dozen or so attempts to make this better, I need to sleep now.
`list_conflicts_1` is the original implementation, while `list_conflicts_2` is [hyde's proposal.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57034169/how-to-optimize-finding-all-meeting-conflicts-below-on2?noredirect=1#comment100597144_57034169)

Good:

- The process has been sped up by 1.5 - 2x its original speed

Bad:

- The new algorithm uses up a lot of memory, far more than the memory used by the original implementation.
- The new algorithm still increases at roughly O(n^2).

**Additional Notes:**

- An attempt was made to use a list of `(id, id)` tuples as the resulting output. Less memory was used, but the result was at least 2x slower than if a dictionary was used.

```py
import functools
import itertools
import operator
import random
import enum
import time
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Tuple, DefaultDict, List, Any, Set

import perfplot
import numpy

def overlap(interval_1: Tuple[int, int, int], interval_2: Tuple[int, int, int]) -> bool:
    return interval_1[1] < interval_2[2] and interval_2[1] < interval_1[2]


def list_conflicts_1(events: List[Tuple[int, int, int]]) -> DefaultDict[Any, List]:
    results = defaultdict(list)
    for i in range(len(events)):
        event_selected = events[i]
        for e in itertools.islice(events, i):
            if overlap(event_selected, e) and (e[0], event_selected[0]) not in results:
                results[e[0]].append(event_selected[0])
                results[event_selected[0]].append(e[0])
    return results


class Token(enum.Enum):
    start = 0
    stop = 1


def list_conflicts_2(events: List[Tuple[int, int, int]]) -> DefaultDict[Any, List]:
    results = defaultdict(list)
    time_list = sorted(
        functools.reduce(operator.iconcat,
            list(([(Token.start, e_id, start), (Token.stop, e_id, end)] for e_id, start, end in events)), []
        ), key=lambda a: a[2])
    stack = []
    for token, t_id, _ in time_list:
        if token == Token.start:
            stack.append(t_id)
            if len(stack) > 1:
                for i in itertools.islice(stack, len(stack) - 1):
                    results[i].append(t_id)
                    results[t_id].append(i)
        if token == Token.stop and t_id in stack:
                stack.remove(t_id)

    return results


def create_t_random(a, b):
    return random.randrange(a, b)


def create_t_precise(x):
    return x

# This portion is a sanity test: Can be ignored
sanity_test_case = sorted([
    (1, create_t_precise(4), create_t_precise(7)),
    (2, create_t_precise(5), create_t_precise(8)),
    (3, create_t_precise(9), create_t_precise(12)),
    (4, create_t_precise(13), create_t_precise(14)),
    (5, create_t_precise(9), create_t_precise(15)),
    (6, create_t_precise(10), create_t_precise(17)),
], key=lambda x: x[1])
assert (list_conflicts_1(sanity_test_case) == list_conflicts_2(sanity_test_case))


def generate_bcs(n):
    return sorted(((i+1, i, i+1) for i in range(n)), key=lambda a: a[1])


def generate_wcs(n):
    return sorted(((i+1, 1, 1000) for i in range(n)), key=lambda a: a[1])


# Best case scenario
perfplot.show(
    setup=generate_bcs,
    kernels=[list_conflicts_1, list_conflicts_2],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(14)],
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
    xlabel='num lists',
    equality_check=lambda x, y: x == y
)

# Worst case scenario
perfplot.show(
    setup=generate_wcs,
    kernels=[list_conflicts_1, list_conflicts_2],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(14)],
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
    xlabel='num lists',
    equality_check=lambda x, y: x == y
)
```

**Results:**

**Best case scenario (no overlap) (BCS):**

[image]

`list_conflicts_2` properties under BCS:

- Time: approximately O(nlogn)
- Memory: roughly O(1)

**Worst case scenario (all overlap) (WCS):**

[image]

`list_conflicts_2` properties under WCS:

- Time: approximately O(n^2)
- Memory: roughly O(n^2)